# Can events in javascript not execute a function by themselves? Are they just used to call a function?

Tags: javascript, function, arrow-functions

Here the following code doesn't work

```
    <body>
          <div id="demo"></div>
          <input type="button" value="Click Here" onclick='()=>{document.getElementById("demo").innerText = "Hello World";}'>
          <script type="text/javascript"></script>
    </body>
```

But the when I create the function and call it through the onclick event, it works

```
<body>
  <div id="demo"></div>
  <input type="button" value="Click Here" onclick='myFunction()'>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function myFunction(){
      document.getElementById("demo").innerText = "Hello World";
    }
  </script>
</body>
```

What is it that I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Defining js inline in the HTML is a bad practice btw...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Intrinsic event attribute values represent the **body** of a function.

Your code is equivalent to:

```
function onclick() {
    ()=>{document.getElementById("demo").innerText = "Hello World";}
}
```

You have defined a function which, when called (by being triggered by a click event) **defines** a function but doesn't call it or assign it anywhere.

As with any function, you can put any statements you like in the function body. They don't need to be function calls.

```
onclick='document.getElementById("demo").innerText = "Hello World";'
```

---

Note that intrinsic event attributes are considered bad practise (they fail to separate concerns, they have some surprising scope implications which can lead to variable name clashes, and they can quickly lead into nested quote character hell). Look to use [the `addEventListener` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) instead.

Comment: This was really helpful. Thank You very much!!